# Any suggestions for creating/refactoring wicket components that enable and/or view associations between entities?

Tags: java, web-applications, refactoring, wicket

My team has been tasked with creating what you can generically call an entity management application. The 3 primary entities being managed are: **Merchants**, **Organizations**, and **Contacts**
Separate pages have been created for the management of each entity. However, many of the functional patterns on these pages are quite similar. The 2 patterns in particular that are repeated everywhere I look are:

- **Pattern 1**: *Associating entity of type Y with entity of type X*
- **Pattern 2**: *Listing entities of type Y that are already associated with entity of type X*

Unfortunately these pages were created adhoc by multiple developers. This has resulted in a hodge-podge of solutions, none of which are readily reusable. So what I want to do is abstract out the two patterns I identified above into reusable components, but I am fairly new to wicket and I'm unsure of the best strategy to use.

My first thought is to encapsulate the patterns in two parameterized component classes that extend panel. But I would like to hear from those with more experience.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:
Forgot to mention, for any wondering, that any of the 3 entities can associate in a many to many relationship with either of the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a pretty good idea to me. Additionally I'd check if any specific logic (like DAOs, Validators and stuff) could be provided via Dependency Injection (Google Guice comes to mind) so you could just use one panel with different handlers/workers/dataproviders for your different usecases.

It's hard to be more specific since your question is kind of broad and a little bit on tue vague side..

Comment: Thanks for the input! Never used Guice b4, I'll look into it. BTW, What sort of extra information could I add to make the my question less vague?

Comment: @klactose This might sound arrogant but isn't meant to be. You were basically asking "I've got a candidate for refactoring. Should I refactor this the way I refactor everything else?". Since Wicket is Java, it can be refactored like Java as long as you'll keep the hierarchy and identifiers intact... Any pitfalls might be hidden in the code you're going to refactor...

Comment: No offense taken at all. I am definitely asking for suggestions on the best path to take when refactoring these web pages, but I suppose the nuance of my question relates to dealing with the relationships between objects in wicket. Since creating pages with lists of related objects is a recurring pattern in web dev, I was hoping that someone might suggest a best practice for use with wicket in particular. Some examples will likely be found in a Wicket Cookbook, but I was looking for some ideas to tide me over until I get my hands on a such a cookbook.